# Fake documentation/code generator or rewriter

Tags: code-generation, documentation-generation

This is a serious question, but the intent is not very serious; it's actually a joke I wanted to play on someone and while thinking about it I got quite interested.

Everyone knows http://pdos.csail.mit.edu/scigen/ I suppose: i was wondering ; is there any kind of code + documentation generator? Something which generates 'plausible' looking (doesn't even have to work) Java code and code documentation for instance?

Seems like a very interesting project to me and I couldn't find anything on Google. Does something like this exist?

Edit: something which would refactor a codebase beyond recognition would be good too; kind of a Markov chain for programming.

Answer (score 0):

Well you could try [Mechanical Turk](https://www.mturk.com/mturk/welcome) if you have a budget for your practical joke. If you are more into an automated solution, a [dissociated press](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dissociated_press) type of algorithm would work.  Call me old fashioned, but I prefer the [real thing](http://thedailywtf.com/) to what these previous two methods could do.

Comment: Well, as you might've guessed from my post; it actually now went from a practical joke to real interest if something like this might be possible to do. I mean, sure, not for 'real', but so it looks plausible to the untrained (or just uninterested) eye, like SCIGen.